# Запятая пред союзом "и" в ССП или БСП

Tags: запятые, ссп, бсп

> А вторым весомым аргументом «за» для меня стал тот факт, что одной из
>   первых на территории тогда ещё полуразрушенного бомбёжкой монастыря
>   оказалась моя подруга. Она – человек далёкий от истории искусств, но
>   переживала трагедию Сербии, как собственную: её любимый был родом из
>   тех мест и, как только была снята военная блокада, они вместе с ним
>   оказались в Милешево.

(МИЛЕШЕВОЙ? МИЛЕШЕВОМ?)

Перенесла запятую: было перед *и,* стало позади. А может, обе нужны?

Comment: Вроде перед И не нужна, п. ч. обе части отдельного ССП подчинены тексту перед двоеточием. В таких случаях, кажется, не ставят запятую между частями.

Comment: Они вместе с ним оказались  - это правильно? Их же двое, а не трое. Может быть, они вместе оказались. Как различить варианты?

Comment: Спасибо, Шаронушко: она вместе с ним. Отвлекают другие моменты, понимаешь ли. И Люся потому же не заметила.

Comment: Тогда уж убрать "с ним": "они вместе  оказались в Милешево."

Comment: Угу. Спасибо! )))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Она – человек далёкий от истории искусств, но переживала трагедию Сербии, как собственную (почему?):(потому что) её любимый был родом из тех мест и, как
>   только была снята военная блокада, они вместе с ним оказались в
>   Милешево.*

Достаточно одной запятой **после** И, **выделяющей начало придаточного предложения времени**, потому что  части ССП поясняют **общую  часть**, отделённую от них двоеточием,указывая на причину,  как, например, здесь: *Останавливаться нельзя: дело на полпути бросать жалко и ухмылки недоброжелателей нежелательны.*

А вот в этой части

> ...переживала трагедию Сербии, как собственную

я бы перед КАК запятую не ставила,т.к. сочетание с как близко примыкает к сказуемому: она не просто переживает, а переживает (как?) как собственное горе, собственную трагедию - в качестве собственной.

> ...они вместе с ним оказались в Милешево.

Верно **в Милешево**, потому что это посёлок, родовое слово (хотя оно и пропущено) и название  разного рода. Если бы это было село, было бы в Милешеве, вот чтоб не спутать с селом, лучше не склонять, хотя название и славянское.

Comment: Люсенька, а у туточки - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7kLerjhll4 - сербка рассказывает, верить нельзя?

Comment: Так они оказались в монастыре или в посёлке? Сербка говорит о монастыре, а в тексте о чём? Если в монастыре, то в монастыре  Милешева, но нужно обязательно слово монастырь, а если в посёлке, то в Милешево.

Comment: Речь о монастыре. Глава называется "Белый Ангел"; так и не знаем, как ангела писать.

Comment: "...так и не знаем, как ангела писать" - Ангел - с большой буквы, конечно, как всё религиозное.

Comment: Оказались в Милешево - нормально смотрится, ведь, говоря о посёлке, вы подразумеваете монастырь. Собственно Милешево - это и посёлок монастырский, и обитель, смотря что иметь в виду, а место одно.

Comment: Ещё раз спасибо. Мы сейчас (с автором) рассказываем о Сербии, много религиозного: будьте на стрёме! )))